# Why URI image is loading incredible slow using PHP

Tags: php, image, performance, uri

I have the following code:

```
$uri_001 = 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/googology/images/f/f3/Test.jpeg/revision/latest?cb=20180121032443';
$uri_link_001 = 'data: '.image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($uri_001)).';base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($uri_001));
```

When I using URI inside `<img src="<?=$uri_link_001?>">`, then serwer response is 2 seconds.

Without URI `<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/googology/images/f/f3/Test.jpeg/revision/latest?cb=20180121032443">` serwer response is 0,5 second.

What I'm doing wrong here and why URI file is so slow when I have more than 1 image with URI?

Comment: The browser might have the image cached.

Comment: @Barmar Near this image in DevTools > Network, I have Size - (from memory cache) and Time - Pending and second image - 2ms. URI works great when I have only 1 image, but If I have 2 on the same page, then page load is very slow.

Comment: `data:` URI doesn't come from the network, it's part of the page itself. The problem is that it's slowing down loading the whole page.

Comment: @Barmar So, what should I do to get faster response from `data:`?

Comment: Do you really have to use `data:`? It can't be cached, unless the whole page is cached. How big is the image? Base64 encoding make it larger.

Comment: @Barmar Both images have 100Kb. What is the minimum weight of image to use Base64?

Comment: There's no maximum. But base64 will make it larger, and make downloading your page take longer. Also, the PHP script has to download the file from the remote site twice, once in `image_type_to_mime_type()` and again in `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: @Barmar I used `image_type_to_mime_type()` and `file_get_contents()`. I still don't exactly understand what you mean. Create this using string like this? `$uri_001 = 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/googology/images/f/f3/Test.jpeg/revision/latest?cb=20180121032443';
  $sh_1 = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($uri_001));
  $sh_2 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($uri_001));
  $uri_link_001 = 'data: '.$sh_1.';base64,'.$sh_2;` What will look full good working code from question I added?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use separate variables. You're still reading the URL twice, once when you get the image type, and again when you get the contents.

Comment: @Barmar Where I read URL twice? If I remove `exif_imagetype` or `file_get_contents`, then `data:` is broken. Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. `exif_imagetype()` just reads the beginning of the file, it doesn't have to download the whole thing.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you remove `exif_imagetype()`, I was just trying to explain why your `data:` method might be slow.